# How to update data after ajax reload using initComplete callback for DataTables when using ajax source data?

Tags: datatables

I’m using a select object to trigger an ajax reload for a DataTable.
I need to add individual column searching with select inputs for a given column (not for every column) but the select is filled with the previous ajax response.
How can I update the data that the initCompleteFunction callback uses to fill the select input in the individual column searching?

```
// this is the select that triggers the ajax.reload

$('#proveedor').on('change', function () {
    $datatable
    .DataTable()
    .ajax
    .reload(initCompleteFunction, false);
});

// this is my initCompleteFunction callback
function initCompleteFunction(settings, json){
    var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );
    api.columns().every( function () {
        var column = this;
        if ($(column.header()).hasClass('select')) {
            var select = $('<select><option value="">' + $(column.header()).html() + '</option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );  
                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                    return false;
                } );

            //this is the part that keeps previous data insted of the new one from the ajax reload
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' );
            } );
        }
    });
}


// and this is how I’m setting the DataTable

var $datatable = $('#table_materiales');

$datatable
.on('xhr.dt', function ( e, settings, json, xhr ) {
    initCompleteFunction(settings, json);        
})
.DataTable({
    "ajax": {
    "url": "http://my_endpoint",
    "dataSrc": "",
    "type": "POST",
    "data": {
        id_proveedor: function () {
            return $('#proveedor').val(); // to get the value in the provider’s filter (select)
        }
    }
    },
    "columns": [
        {
            data: 'row_num'
        },{
            className: "select",
            data: 'material'
        },        
        // here goes the rest of the column definitions
    ],
    "paging": false,
    'columnDefs': [
    {
        'targets': 0,
        'checkboxes': {
            'selectRow': true
        }
    }
    ],
    'select': {
        'style': 'multi'
    },
    'order': [
        [3, 'asc']
    ],
    "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
        $(row).attr('data-id-material', data.id_material); 
        $(row).attr('data-pedido_sugerido', data.pedido_sugerido);
        $(row).attr('id', 'id_' + data.row_num); 
        
        if(data['status_de_tiempo']=='FUERA'){
            $(row).addClass('redClass');
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

During research I found that the xhr.dt event is triggered before the ajax.reload() is completed so the data keeps outdated when the select for the individual column search is populated. See [this reference](http://mail.datatables.net/forums/discussion/55764/ajax-reload-callback-function-doesnt-wait-until-xhr-completes)

User grozni posted this on April, 2019:

> I have used console logs and was able to confirm that **the event fires before the XHR event concludes, and does not pull the latest JSON**. I used XHR tracking where I could to get around it but it's still really inconvenient and complicating matters alot. I need to be able to do certain things after the data is loaded and drawn. Perhaps it's worthy of a bug report

I found this post ([See here](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/2146)) where user conangithub needed to

> count DataTables item after I reload DataTable successfully

User lovecoding-git suggested this approach:

```
table= $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example').on('draw.dt', function() {
    console.log(table.ajax.json().recordsTotal);
});
```

So, for my own issue, instead of

```
.on('xhr.dt', function ( e, settings, json, xhr ) {
    initCompleteFunction(settings, json);        
})
```

I wrote

```
.on('draw.dt', function ( e, settings, json, xhr ) {
    initCompleteFunction(settings, json);        
})
```

Et voilà.

I got the needed solution.